# Nested dict key overwritten

Tags: python

I want to create a nested dict through a for loop. All the customers and categories keys are created as expected (i and j), but for the product_categories only the last key is written. I know it's probably getting overwritten, but I can't understand why?

```
top_10_recs = {}

for i, j, k in itertools.product(customers, categories, product_categories):
    if i not in top_10_recs:
        top_10_recs[i] = {}
    if j not in top_10_recs:
        top_10_recs[i][j] = {}
    if k not in top_10_recs:
        top_10_recs[i][j][k] = {}
    try:
        top_10_recs[i][j][k] = trained_dataframe.loc[(i, j), k].nlargest(10).to_dict()
    except:
        pass
```

If I do a print with this:

```
for i, j, k in itertools.product(customers, categories, product_categories):
    try:
        print("{}".format(k))
        print(trained_dataframe.loc[(i, j), k].nlargest(10))
```

I get the expected result, looping through all product_categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful to only create new keys inside dictionaries if they do not already exist in those dictionaries. The snippet below should work.

```
if i not in top_10_recs:
    top_10_recs[i] = {}
if j not in top_10_recs[i]:
    top_10_recs[i][j] = {}
if k not in top_10_recs[i][j]:
    top_10_recs[i][j][k] = {}
```

Consider also using `except KeyError` instead of just `except`, which catches all possible errors (you do not want that).

Comment: Thanks! Now all the customers and product_categories (i and k) are written to the dict, but only one category (j)

Comment: I may have misunderstood then. Let's consider the first customer object. You create a first entry which contains a new dictionary. Then, in this new dictionary, do you want as many keys (and thereby new inner dictionaries) as you have objects in categories, or just one ?

Comment: Yes, I want to have all the objects in categories as keys in the dict

Comment: @joddm I have just understood the itertools.product() behaviour. Sorry for that, not used to using it, but it is indeed really powerful. Please see the updated code above. The key is indeed to only create inner directories if they have not already been created, and there is no need for indentation as I had previously suggested, because of the behavior of itertools.product(). I hope it works now.

Comment: Pleasure, thank you for making me discover itertools.product(). :)